# Terraform recipe to create elasticsearch domain seems to be hanging

Tags: elasticsearch, terraform

I have a terraform recipe which seems to be either hanging, or trying to asynchronously do the same thing A LOT of times and getting tripped up.

Here is the main code :

```
resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "es" {
  domain_name = "${var.es_domain}"
  elasticsearch_version = "6.3"

  cluster_config {
    instance_type = "t2.medium.elasticsearch"
  }

  count = "${var.staff_count}"
  vpc_options {

    subnet_ids = [
      "${aws_subnet.public_subnets.*.id[count.index]}"
    ]

    security_group_ids = [
      "${aws_security_group.es_sg.id}"
    ]
  }

  ebs_options {
    ebs_enabled = true
    volume_size = 10
  }

  access_policies = <<CONFIG
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Action": "es:*",
          "Principal": "*",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:es:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:domain/${var.es_domain}/*"
      }
  ]
}
  CONFIG

  snapshot_options {
    automated_snapshot_start_hour = 23
  }

  tags {
    Domain = "${var.es_domain}"
  }
}
```

Here is the "public subnets" code :

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets" {
  count = "${var.staff_count}"
  cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, count.index)}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  availability_zone = "${var.region}${var.az}"

  tags = "${merge(map("Name", "${var.company_name}-staff-${count.index}-subnet")
  , map("kubernetes.io/cluster/staff-${count.index}", "owned"))}"
}
```

Here is the variable for my domain :

```
variable "es_domain" {
  default = "my-es-domain"
  description = "Domain name for elastic search."
}
```

And I have a staff_count variable which is "8"

Now, I would have expected the result to be that upon running this code, I would get ONE elasticSearch domain, with a subnet for each member of staff...

Now, that doesn't seem to be what is happening, I seem to get all caught up on an infinite loop (or some sort of race condition?) which goes on for over an hour until everything times out.

I get a whole bunch of errors which look exactly like the one below, but with a different number

```
* aws_elasticsearch_domain.es.3: "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:01043847838460:domain/my-es-domain": Timeout while waiting for the domain to be created
* module.init.aws_elasticsearch_domain.es[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:
```

Seems like it is trying to do it a whole bunch of times at once, right? If that is the case, I'd really love some guidance on how to fix it, I am new to terraform and am baffled by the syntax.

Comment: Your code is saying to create multiple ES domains but I'm confused what you're actually trying to achieve here. Why do you want a subnet for each member of staff? The subnets for the ES domain is for which subnets to place nodes of your ES domain in, you just want to spread it across availability zones for fault tolerance really unless you have some very special use case here that you haven't described?

Comment: I don't have a special use case - this is an elastic search instance which is made available to staff who are training to use our stack - We just need to spin up one Elastic Search cluster, but need to have a subnet for each "person"

Comment: @ydaetskcoR did you say my code says to create multiple? Because that is what I need to stop happening!

Comment: What do you mean by a subnet for each person?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I am essentially trying to create one elastic search cluster, and give access to everyone. Maybe subnets are not what I want - but I really just would like to change this to get one elasticSearch cluster

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - maybe it would help if I paste the VPC stuff here, too? that way you might see more about what i am trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

> `count = "${var.staff_count}"`

This is the source of your multiple clusters. The count property indicates how many to make.